# Access camera in blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, camera

i am developing an application for blackberry which will take snap from camera and post this image to server.Can someone provide code for me to how invoke camera and take picture and send it to server.?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What device/OS you targeting? Do you want full automation or it's acceptable to demand some users action (take photo, save file into folder etc)?

Comment: i am building app for 4.7 and there is a button when user clicks on it camera will open and as he take picture it will save to server.
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Camera Demo in the samples that will solve the problem

enjoy coding............